# Oracle SQL - Output Result are not as expected output with coalesce

Tags: sql, oracle

I have meet the following issue.

This is the result I expected:

[image: image path]

But this is the result I got:

[image: image path]

The coding;

```
SELECT CVRGVEHICLEID
       , LISTAGG(COALESCE(WIND1,',')
                || COALESCE(NAMEDDRIV1,',')
                || COALESCE(LLPGER1,',')
                || COALESCE(PERIL1,',')
                || COALESCE(SRCC1,',')
                || COALESCE(CART1,',')
                || COALESCE(OTHITEM1,',')) 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CVRGVEHICLEID) FLAG
FROM(
    SELECT CH_MOTOR_CAMP_BASE.CVRGVEHICLEID,
           CASE WHEN ADDON_WIND <> '0' THEN 'WIND' END WIND1,
           CASE WHEN ADDON_NAMEDDRIV <> '0' THEN 'NAMEDDRIV' END NAMEDDRIV1,
           CASE WHEN ADDON_LLPGER <> '0' THEN 'LLPGER' END LLPGER1,
           CASE WHEN ADDON_PERIL <> '0' THEN 'PERIL' END PERIL1,
           CASE WHEN ADDON_SRCC <> '0' THEN 'SRCC' END SRCC1,
           CASE WHEN ADDON_CART <> '0' THEN 'CART' END CART1,
           CASE WHEN ADDON_OTHITEM <> '0' THEN 'OTHITEM' END OTHITEM1
    FROM CH_MOTOR_CAMP_BASE, CH_MOTCAMP_VEHITEM_TRANS
    WHERE CH_MOTOR_CAMP_BASE.CVRGVEHICLEID = CH_MOTCAMP_VEHITEM_TRANS.CVRGVEHICLEID (+)
    )
GROUP BY CVRGVEHICLEID;
```

Comment: Oh right....the results are all just a sample....
The result I am expecting is that, e.g.
WIND,LLPGER,CART
not,
WINDNAMEDDRIV,,,,,WINDNAMEDDRIV

Comment: Please post sample data as text, not images. Many of us can't open the images from our workstation machines and it is difficult to recreate the scenario even if we could.

Answer (score 0):

LISTAGG is for concatenating values from the same column across multiple rows. It seems like you're trying to concatenating multiple columns for each record, with some formatting (commas) when between populated columns.

I suggest you try something like this, which just uses the concatenation operator and `nvl2()` to test whether the previous column was populated and so the next one needs a comma. Also it generates the `'-- NO ADDON --'` flag.

```
select cvrgvehicleid
       , case 
            when noaddon1 is not null then noaddon1
            else rtrim(
                 wind1
                 || nvl2(wind1, ',', null) || nameddriv1
                 || nvl2(nameddriv1, ',', null) || llpger1
                 || nvl2(llpger1, ',', null) || peril1
                 || nvl2(peril1, ',', null) || srcc1
                 || nvl2(srcc1, ',', null) || cart1
                 || nvl2(cart1, ',', null) || othitem1
                  , ',')
         end flag
from(
    select ch_motor_camp_base.cvrgvehicleid,
           case when addon_wind <> '0' then 'WIND' end wind1,
           case when addon_nameddriv <> '0' then 'NAMEDDRIV' end nameddriv1,
           case when addon_llpger <> '0' then 'LLPGER' end llpger1,
           case when addon_peril <> '0' then 'PERIL' end peril1,
           case when addon_srcc <> '0' then 'SRCC' end srcc1,
           case when addon_cart <> '0' then 'CART' end cart1,
           case when addon_othitem <> '0' then 'OTHITEM' end othitem1,
           case when addon_wind = '0' 
               and addon_nameddriv = '0' 
               and addon_llpger = '0' 
               and addon_peril = '0' 
               and addon_srcc = '0' 
               and addon_cart = '0' 
               and addon_othitem  '0' then '-- NO ADDON --' end noaddon1
    from ch_motor_camp_base, ch_motcamp_vehitem_trans
    where ch_motor_camp_base.cvrgvehicleid = ch_motcamp_vehitem_trans.cvrgvehicleid (+)
    )
group by cvrgvehicleid;
```

Note: untested because you have not provided sample test data. Your actual scenario is a bit unclear, so guessing at the raw data is too much of a risk.